# Is there any way using which I can get Last Updated row Id

Tags: mysql, get, rowid

Is there any way using which I can get the last row I have updated of the table.

For Ex:- my table has 1000 records in it.
I have updated the value of 500th record of table X.
So, I want the ID 500 in return.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this feature exists with MySQL. However you can get the same effect by adding a timestamp column:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
   ADD COLUMN last_update TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This would make the last_update column pretty much automatically maintained. Now you can select from yourtable the last updated row based on the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It is a great help.